# Why does it say the parameter, floatingActionButton, isn't defined?

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button

I am getting error in using `FloatingActionButton` which I don't know what means. My code is currently:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('MY First app'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('hello mc lomesss'),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
error: The named parameter 'floatingActionButton' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:12)
error: The named parameter 'onPressed' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. (missing_required_argument at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:12)
info: Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance. (prefer_const_constructors at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:7)
info: Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance. (prefer_const_constructors at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:10)
info: The 'child' argument should be last in widget constructor invocations. (sort_child_properties_last at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:11)
info: Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance. (prefer_const_constructors at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:11)
info: Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance. (prefer_const_constructors at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:12)
info: Use 'const' with the constructor to improve performance. (prefer_const_constructors at [untitled3] lib\main.dart:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a parameter of the `Scaffold` widget, not the `Center`'s.

```
class FabExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const FabExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('FloatingActionButton Sample'),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Press the button below!')),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          // Add your onPressed code here!
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.navigation),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

For more information; https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FloatingActionButton-class.html